# Scrapy not loading entire page? Or I have bad code...

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

I am having issues with pagination in the following code.

The spider starts but does not find any links on the first page. This is because the page actually returns a partial result... I know it sounds odd but its true, when I visit the page I see jobs listed but when the bot visits, there are no jobs listed.

From what I understand, scrapy will load the entire page regardless of JS or AJAX but I am starting to wonder...

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from northrop.items import NorthropItem
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
import re

class NorthropSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "northropJobStart"

  start_urls = ['https://ngc.taleo.net/careersection/ngc_pro/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en#']
  allowed_domains = ["ngc.taleo.net"]

  rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="next"]/a',)), callback="parse_listings", follow= True),
  )

  def parse_start_url(self, response):
    return self.parse_listings(response)

  def parse_listings(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    # There are no jobs listed.. I am lost.....
    jobs = sel.xpath('//th/div/div/span/a/@href').extract()
    for job_url in jobs:
      job_url = self.__normalise(job_url)
      job_url = self.__to_absolute_url(response.url,job_url)
      yield Request(job_url, callback=self.parse_details)

  def parse_details(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    job = sel.xpath('//*[@id="mainbody-jobs"]')
    item = NorthropItem()
    # Populate job fields
    item['title'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="mainbody-jobs"]/h1/text()').extract()
    item['location'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="mainbody-jobs"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/text()').extract()
    item['applink'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="mainbody-jobs"]/div[3]/div[1]/a/@href').extract()
    item['description'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="mainbody-jobs"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]').extract()
    item['travel'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="mainbody-jobs"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[2]/text()').extract()
    item['job_category'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="mainbody-jobs"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()').extract()
    item['clearance_have'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="mainbody-jobs"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[8]/div[2]/text()').extract()
    item['clearance_get'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="mainbody-jobs"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[8]/div[2]/text()').extract()
    item['job_number'] = job.xpath('//*[@id="mainbody-jobs"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/text()').extract()
    item['page_url'] = response.url
    item = self.__normalise_item(item, response.url)
    return item



  def __normalise_item(self, item, base_url):
    '''
    Standardise and format item fields
    '''
    # Loop item fields to sanitise data and standardise data types
    for key, value in vars(item).values()[0].iteritems():
      item[key] = self.__normalise(item[key])
      # Convert job URL from relative to absolute URL
      #item['job_url'] = self.__to_absolute_url(base_url, item['job_url'])
      return item

  def __normalise(self, value):
    # Convert list to string
    value = value if type(value) is not list else ' '.join(value)
    # Trim leading and trailing special characters (Whitespaces, newlines, spaces, tabs, carriage returns)
    value = value.strip()
    return value

  def __to_absolute_url(self, base_url, link):
    '''
    Convert relative URL to absolute URL
    '''
    import urlparse
    link = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, link)
    return link

  def __to_int(self, value):
    '''
    Convert value to integer type
    '''
    try:
      value = int(value)
    except ValueError:
      value = 0
    return value

  def __to_float(self, value):
    '''
    Convert value to float type
    '''
    try:
      value = float(value)
    except ValueError:
      value = 0.0
    return value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the search form is hidden in quite deep but you can see it if in the network tab of your browser inspect.
Turns out it's sending a full json of default search parameters, so you need to pretty much copy and paste it only incrementing the `pageNo`. I couldn't help but solve it and before you know it I wrote a whole spider, so here it is, let me know if some parts are unclear:

```
import json
import scrapy


class TaleoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'taleo'
    start_urls = ['https://ngc.taleo.net/careersection/ngc_pro/jobsearch.ftl?lang=en#']
    # baseform with base search values
    base_form = {'advancedSearchFiltersSelectionParam':
        {'searchFilterSelections': [
            {'id': 'ORGANIZATION', 'selectedValues': []},
            {'id': 'LOCATION', 'selectedValues': []},
            {'id': 'JOB_FIELD', 'selectedValues': []},
            {'id': 'URGENT_JOB', 'selectedValues': []},
            {'id': 'EMPLOYEE_STATUS', 'selectedValues': []},
            {'id': 'STUDY_LEVEL', 'selectedValues': []},
            {'id': 'WILL_TRAVEL', 'selectedValues': []},
            {'id': 'JOB_SHIFT', 'selectedValues': []},
            {'id': 'JOB_NUMBER', 'selectedValues': []}]},
        'fieldData': {'fields': {'JOB_TITLE': '', 'KEYWORD': '', 'LOCATION': ''},
                      'valid': True},
        'filterSelectionParam': {'searchFilterSelections': [{'id': 'POSTING_DATE',
                                                             'selectedValues': []},
                                                            {'id': 'LOCATION', 'selectedValues': []},
                                                            {'id': 'JOB_FIELD', 'selectedValues': []},
                                                            {'id': 'JOB_TYPE', 'selectedValues': []},
                                                            {'id': 'JOB_SCHEDULE', 'selectedValues': []},
                                                            {'id': 'JOB_LEVEL', 'selectedValues': []}]},
        'multilineEnabled': False,
        'pageNo': 1,  # <--- change this for pagination
        'sortingSelection': {'ascendingSortingOrder': 'false',
                             'sortBySelectionParam': '3'}}

    def parse(self, response):
        # we got cookies from first start url now lets request into the search api
        # copy base form for the first request
        form = self.base_form.copy()
        yield scrapy.Request('https://ngc.taleo.net/careersection/rest/jobboard/searchjobs?lang=en&portal=2160420105',
                             body=json.dumps(self.base_form),
                             # add headers to indicate we are sending a json package
                             headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                             # scrapy.Request defaults to 'GET', but we want 'POST' here
                             method='POST',
                             # load our form into meta so we can reuse it later
                             meta={'form': form},
                             callback=self.parse_items)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)
        # scrape data
        for item in data['requisitionList']:
            yield item

        # next page
        # get our form back and update the page number in it
        form = response.meta['form']
        form['pageNo'] += 1
        # check if paging is over, is our next page higher than maximum page?
        max_page = data['pagingData']['totalCount'] / data['pagingData']['pageSize']
        if form['pageNo'] > max_page:
            return
        yield scrapy.Request('https://ngc.taleo.net/careersection/rest/jobboard/searchjobs?lang=en&portal=2160420105',
                             body=json.dumps(form),
                             headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                             method='POST',
                             meta={'form': form},
                             callback=self.parse_items)
```

Comment: It looks like you just parsed the search result pages JSON Data. I need to take links from that data and pass them through to a loop to scrape the details from the pages within. I will work on this tonight and let you know how it goes.

Comment: By the way, I put this on GitHub in case I need more help going forward. I cant work on it until tonight when I get off work from this job.

https://github.com/jsbake2/northrop-scraper

Comment: I actually think I can simply build the URL based on the jobId field and then send that into another def to pull the details I need... Wish I could work on it right now!